# Subscriber status using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, subscriber

Is there a way to retrieve the Susbcriber status using REST API, we could only achive this by 'embeding' a SOAP call in a rest request.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way to retrieve Subscriber and list information is using the SOAP API, therefore you'll need to send a SOAP request.

**Current functionalities available in the REST-API are:**

> - Contacts
> - Content Builder
> - Journey Builder
> - Mobile Connect
> - MobilePush
> - Campaigns
> - Triggered Sends (may also use SOAP)
>
> (Source: [Intro to Marketing Cloud APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm))

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use this method?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/fetchAttributes.htm

**Example:**

```
{
    "request": {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "key": "Email Addresses.Email Address"
            },
            {
                "key": "Profile Data.Age"
            },
            {
                "key": "Profile Data.Gender"
            }
            ]

    },
    "conditionSet": {
        "operator": "And",
        "conditionSets": [],
        "conditions": [{
            "attribute": {
                "key": "Email Addresses.Email Address"
            },
            "operator": "Equals",
            "value": {
                "items": ["someone@someone.com","unauth@someone.com"]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to send a SOAP API call, using this lets say 'embedded' soap call in REST API call, it works:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
  -H 'SOAPAction: \"Retrieve\"' \
  -d '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com"><**Bearer**></fueloauth>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">>
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
            <Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>SubscriberKey</Property>
                   <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                   <Value><**SubscriberKey**></Value> 
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'
```

Comment: This is a SOAP-API call.